# Data is not returned to future build in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, listview, flutter-futurebuilder

```
...
Future<List<Category>> fetchCategorys(id) async {
  var body = jsonEncode({"service_id": id});
  print("service_id : " + id);
  http.Response response2 = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull(api + "get_order_product_details.php"), //url
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
      body: body);
  if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
    // Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response2.body);
    // var map = json.decode(response.body);
    // print("map : " + "${response.body}");
    // print("map : " + "${map['Data']}");
    List<Category> albumList;
    albumList = (json.decode(response2.body) as List)
        .map((i) => Category.fromJson(i))
        .toList()`enter code here`;
    return albumList;
  } else {
    // print("Failed to load categories");
    throw Exception('Failed to load category products');
  }
}
...
```

In this, the returned album list is not coming to the snapshot in future builder

```
...
 child: FutureBuilder<List<Category>>(
          future: fetchCategorys(id),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print("snapshot data : " + "${snapshot.data}");
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              ));
            } else {
...
```

Here the print is printed as 'I/flutter ( 6977): snapshot data : null'

Comment: When i run the app the loading text appears

Comment: please help to get the data

Comment: Have you tried adding `<List<Category>>` in the `AsyncSnapshot`? `builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Category>> snapshot)`

Comment: I tried that but still the snapshot.data = null

Comment: print("map : " + "${map['Data']}");

Comment: this print prints the data but the code after that is not working

Comment: The list is inside the ['Data'] key? Can you try `albumList = (json.decode(response2.body)['Data'] as List)`

Comment: Thnx that worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the future is throwing error you should check the error state on future builder too. Check the official docs to find out how to check all the states
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#widgets.FutureBuilder.1